# Request causing app to crash

Tags: ios

i have this app which has a viewcontroller in which there are 3 tabs portfolio , list , categories and each tab has a view which on clicking shows the respective view. When the user opens the viewcontroller the portfolio tab is shown as default which loads images from a webservice the code is this the problem is that `

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",WEBSITE_URL]]];
Communication *comm = [[Communication alloc] initWithUrlRequest:request];
comm.request_name = request_name;
comm.delegate = self;
[comm startAsynchronous];
[request release];
```

the problem is that if i open the view controller and quickly click on another tab the app crashes i mean each time i have to give a fiew second for the request to load the portfolio or otherwise the app crashes if i go back to another view controller and then click this view controller a few times then the app also crashes 
please help

Comment: Please show the details of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the ongoing request (or set the delegate to nil). Otherwise it will call the delegate, which is not present any more.

// edit

I don't know how you implemented `Communication`, but the normal way would be to call `cancel` on the corresponding `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: please tell me how to cancel it

Comment: As @Vova stated: please post the error - otherwise it will be pure guessing.

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/j608mojptdpyny0/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-02%20at%202.35.49%20PM.png

Comment: Did you check that `[self delegate]` is not `nil`?

Comment: i dont think i have set any delegate nil ... please do tell me which delegate to set nil and how it would effect the app .. thanks a Loads  @tilo

Comment: just do a `NSLog(@"Delegate: %@",[self delegate]);` and check that the delegate actually exists

Comment: i got the first issue resolved because i once initialized the request = [[nsmutablerequest alloc]init]; in the view did load and then again in the button of the tab on the same viewcontroller .... now the problem is when i go back to another viewcontroller and come back to the one with request a multiple times quickly then app crashes